# google script mark row one at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to add programatically the status for each row. I have a list of clients and I'd like to send some e-mails using Google Script.

My question is why it doesn't reaches to the last row ?

My code looks like:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 4);

  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName(TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME);
  var emailSubject = templateSheet.getRange(EMAIL_SUBJECT_CELL_RANGE).getValue();
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_CELL_RANGE).getValue();

  // Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
  objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

  // For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
  // it to the appropriate person.
  for (var i = 1; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
   var rowData = objects[i];
   //Logger.log(rowData.status);
    // Generate a personalized email.
    // Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) with
    // the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
    var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
    var msgPlain = emailText.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""); // clear html tags for plain mail
  if (rowData.status == EMAIL_NOT_SENT) {
    //MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.email, emailSubject, msgPlain, { htmlBody: emailText });

    var statusCell = dataSheet.getRange(i+1,4,1);

    if (!isCellEmpty(statusCell) && statusCell.getValue() != STATUS_COLUMN_NAME) {
      Logger.log(statusCell.getA1Notation());
      Logger.log(objects.length);
      //statusCell.setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Logging output:

```
[14-09-24 03:17:45:161 EEST] D2
[14-09-24 03:17:45:162 EEST] 5.0
[14-09-24 03:17:45:166 EEST] D3
[14-09-24 03:17:45:166 EEST] 5.0
[14-09-24 03:17:45:170 EEST] D4
[14-09-24 03:17:45:170 EEST] 5.0
[14-09-24 03:17:45:173 EEST] D5
[14-09-24 03:17:45:174 EEST] 5.0
```

Comment: I have not tested it but it seems you are skipping the first object in rowsData. Try looping over for(var i=0; i<objects.length; i++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
for (var i = 1; i < objects.length; ++i) {
```

is iterating from 1 to 4 (since object.length = 5) because object properties (like arrays) are 0 indexed.

Sheet methods (like `getRange()`) are counting from 1 (there is no row 0 ) so when you use

```
var statusCell = dataSheet.getRange(i+1,4,1);
```

you are targeting the wrong row (the one above the corresponding data).

You can solve that issue very simply by using

`var statusCell = dataSheet.getRange(i+2,4,1);`

+1 to compensate the index difference and +1 to skip the headers.

You could have found this yourself easily by Logging the value of i (that would show 1,2,3,4) and corresponding properties of rowData (rowData for i=1 is sheet row 3, rowData for i=2 is sheet row 4, etc )